# How can I pull values from varying, specific rows in a separate workbook?

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I have a code which I generated for the purpose of sending Outlook emails to clients who are overdue on invoice payments.

Currently, the code pulls data from cells in a workbook - "WB 1" - which I have manually input for each of our invoices into an email.

It then adds an email signature using `SendKeys` (I know this function is not favorable but I had troubles with other workarounds).

The code finally waits 5 seconds (to avoid any lag affecting the `SendKeys`) and repeats for as many invoices as selected in "WB 1".

What I would like to do is be able to incorporate within the code the ability to take the invoice number from "WB 1" and search the same value in our invoice log workbook - "WB 2".

I would like to then copy values from approximately 5 specific columns within that invoice number's row into "WB 1", which would mean I wouldn't have to manually transfer these values over for each and every invoice we send, benefiting efficiency of the process.

I have tried using the `Find` function but unfortunately with my limited knowledge in coding and a self taught beginner I am experiencing some problems.

Please let me know if I've made my explanation convoluted and I will be happy to discuss further.

Thank you for your time.

```
Sub DunningEmailv2()
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim cell As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

On Error GoTo cleanup
For Each cell In Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
       LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "C").Value) = "yes" Then

        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
            .SentOnBehalfOfName = "xxx@xxx.xxx"
            .Importance = olImportanceHigh
            .To = cell.Value
            .Subject = "Overdue Invoice Reminder from xxx"
            .Body = "Dear " & Cells(cell.Row, "A").Value & "," _
                  & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                  Cells(cell.Row, "D").Value & " have an outstanding invoice numbered (" & Cells(cell.Row, "E").Value & ")" & ", amounting to $" & Cells(cell.Row, "G").Value & "." _
                  & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                    "This invoice is now " & Cells(cell.Row, "H").Value & " days overdue which has become a concern for us." _
                  & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                    "Please provide confirmation as to when payment will be made." _
                  & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                    "If you have any questions please feel free to ask." _
                  & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                    "Kind regards," _


            '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
            .Save
            .Display    


                    Dim currenttime As Date

                    currenttime = Now
                    Do Until currenttime + TimeValue("00:00:05") <= Now
                    Loop


            SendKeys "^+{End}", True
            SendKeys "{End}", True
            SendKeys "%nas~", True

        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set OutMail = Nothing
    End If
Next cell

cleanup:
Set OutApp = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: To be clear, you want to copy data from `WB 2` to `WB 1`?

Comment: Correct @Petrichor

Answer (score 0):

You can adapt this example from [here](http://ccm.net/faq/24666-copy-data-to-another-workbook-in-excel)

```
    Sub CopyOpenItems() 
   ' 
   ' CopyOpenItems Macro 
   ' Copy open items to sheet. 
   ' 
   ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+O 
   ' 
   Dim wbTarget            As Workbook 'workbook where the data is to be pasted 
   Dim wbThis              As Workbook 'workbook from where the data is to be copied 
   Dim strName             As String   'name of the source sheet/ target workbook 

   'set to the current active workbook (the source book) 
   Set wbThis = ActiveWorkbook 

   'get the active sheetname of the book 
   strName = ActiveSheet.Name 

   'open a workbook that has same name as the sheet name 
   Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open("C:\filepath\" & strName & ".xlsx") 

   'select cell A1 on the target book 
   wbTarget.Range("A1").Select 

   'clear existing values form target book 
   wbTarget.Range("A1:M51").ClearContents 

   'activate the source book 
   wbThis.Activate 

   'clear any thing on clipboard to maximize available memory 
   Application.CutCopyMode = False 

   'copy the range from source book 
   wbThis.Range("A12:M62").Copy 

   'paste the data on the target book 
   wbTarget.Range("A1").PasteSpecial 

   'clear any thing on clipboard to maximize available memory 
   Application.CutCopyMode = False 

   'save the target book 
   wbTarget.Save 

   'close the workbook 
   wbTarget.Close 

   'activate the source book again 
   wbThis.Activate 

   'clear memory 
   Set wbTarget = Nothing 
   Set wbThis = Nothing 

End Sub
```

Comment: I appreciate your feedback however I am unsure as to how I could manipulate the above code to read a specific value and retrieve data from another worksheet's row which includes the aforementioned value.